# Functions within loops C++

Tags: c++, function, loops

I'm using OpenGL to load a lot of different textures. As I'm loading a lot of textures though I have around 50 lines that are all calls of the same function, I was just wondering if there is a way to condense this or make it more efficient.

For reference here is what the function call and a section of the code looks like:

```
//Load the barrier texture image
LoadTexture("barrier/ConcreteBarrier_Texture_stripes.jpg", textureId3, true);
//Load the shed texture image
LoadTexture("shed/shed1.jpg", textureId4, true);
//Load the banana texture image
LoadTexture("banana/Banana_D01.png", textureId5, true);
//Load the UI button 1 image
LoadTexture("ui/button1.png", textureIdB1, false);
//Load the UI button 2 image
LoadTexture("ui/button2.png", textureIdB2, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the values into an array, and then loop through the array calling the function, eg:

```
struct paramInfo {
    string file;
    GLuint id;
    bool b;
};

paramInfo params[] = {
    {"barrier/ConcreteBarrier_Texture_stripes.jpg", textureId3, true},
    {"shed/shed1.jpg", textureId4, true},
    {"banana/Banana_D01.png", textureId5, true},
    {"ui/button1.png", textureIdB1, false},
    {"ui/button2.png", textureIdB2, false}, 
    ...
};

for (auto &p : params) {
    LoadTexture(p.file.c_str(), p.id, p.b);
}
```